# Pulling Items from JSON: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm currently playing with react-static and integrating data from our CMS.  I'm sure this is something very basic, but I'm brain fried and can't see what I'm missing.  In short, I'm pulling a JSON of nav items from the menu of the CMS.  The individual nav items are contained in the items key of the menu object.  I'm trying to iterate through them and build my nav components.

If I just set the variable to the items object, it builds fine.  However because its an object within an object I can't seem to dig down enough correctly.

Here is my function

```
renderMenu() {
      return menus.items.map((menu) => {
          return (
              <NavItem>
                  <Link to={menu.object_slug} className="nav-link">{menu.title}</Link>
              </NavItem>
          )
      })
  }
```

Here is a small sample of the JSON

```
{
  "ID" : 2,
  "name" : Primary Navigation,
  "slug" : primary-navigation,
  "description" : ,
  "count" : 9,
  "items" : -[
    -{
      "id" : 11,
      "order" : 1,
      "parent" : 0,
      "title" : About,
      "url" : http:\/\/www.attorneytemplate.dev.php72-38.lan3-      1.websitetestlink.com\/about\/,
      "attr" : ,
      "target" : ,
      "classes" : ,
      "xfn" : ,
      "description" : ,
      "object_id" : 2,
      "object" : page,
      "object_slug" : about,
      "type" : post_type,
      "type_label" : Page
      },
    {
      "id" : 21,
      "order" : 2,
      "parent" : 0,
      "title" : Practice Areas,
      "url" : #,
      "attr" : ,
      "target" : ,
      "classes" : ,
      "xfn" : ,
      "description" : ,
      "object_id" : 21,
      "object" : custom,
      "object_slug" : practice-areas,
      "type" : custom,
      "type_label" : Custom Link,
      "children" : -[
        -{
          "id" : 26,
          "order" : 3,
          "parent" : 21,
          "title" : Practice Area 1,
          "url" : http:\/\/www.attorneytemplate.dev.php72-38.lan3-1.websitetestlink.com\/practice-area\/practice-area-1\/,
          "attr" : ,
          "target" : ,
          "classes" : ,
          "xfn" : ,
          "description" : ,
          "object_id" : 13,
          "object" : practice-area,
          "object_slug" : practice-area-1,
          "type" : post_type,
          "type_label" : Practice Area
        },
        {
          "id" : 25,
          "order" : 4,
          "parent" : 21,
          "title" : Practice Area 2,
          "url" : http:\/\/www.attorneytemplate.dev.php72-38.lan3-1.websitetestlink.com\/practice-area\/practice-area-2\/,
          "attr" : ,
          "target" : ,
          "classes" : ,
          "xfn" : ,
          "description" : ,
          "object_id" : 15,
          "object" : practice-area,
          "object_slug" : practice-area-2,
          "type" : post_type,
          "type_label" : Practice Area
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Also, secondary question how would I handle the children items?

Comment: Where is located the `renderMenu() ` function? It seems that `menus` object is undefined.

Comment: You can recreate your code in https://codesandbox.io/s/new and share it with us, it will be more easier to help you.

Comment: you need to put the complete code for us to debug. are you fetching this menu object in willmount or didmount?

Comment: Here is my code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/3x4o51q4k5

Comment: So below I'm working through building the loop correctly.  As far as importing in my menu data, I am building it in static.config.js and importing it with 

`import menus from '../static.config'

Comment: Here is the live build since the codesandbox only has the relevant code.  http://attorneytemplate.netlify.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you don't pass correctly the 'menus' object to the component that contains the `renderMenu()` function.

I've created a menu based on your Json example and it seems that it renders just fine:

https://codesandbox.io/s/k5plnv2vm5

In order to iterate through children items, add this code:

```
return menus.items.map((menu, i) => {
  return (
    <div key={i}>
      <a href={menu.object_slug} className="nav-link">{menu.title}</a>
      {(menu.children) ? (
        menu.children.map((children, i) => {
          return (
            <li key={'children-'+i}>
              <a href={children.object_slug} className="nav-link">{children.title}</a>
            </li>
          )
        })
      ): null}
    </div>
  )
})
```

Comment: With 2 parts to this question, I'm trying to work through both.  Here is my codepin trying to implement your loop.  My hurdle is if there are children I need to alter that parent's iteration by adding some container components.

https://codesandbox.io/s/3x4o51q4k5

Comment: Here is the live build since the codesandbox only has the relevant code.  http://attorneytemplate.netlify.com/